# Как проверить в строке БД все столбцы на true или false

Tags: c#, linq, discord, entity-framework-core

Хочу сделать систему квестов, знаю как её сделать через if но их будет много, и в целом это будет плохой код. Расскажу свою задумку, когда пользователь выполнил квест в бд идет значение true, после этого тот квест который у него выполнен будет отображаться в профиле в виде значка, я не понимаю как мне сделать проверку всей строки пользователя в бд на наличия true false. Мой проект дискорд бот библиотека discord.net

мне нужно, чтобы находился айди юзера и айди гильдии, а все остальные столбцы была проверка на true or false
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
[Command("q")]
    public async Task questcheck ()
    {
        var user = QuestsDb.GetUserQuests(Context.User.Id, Context.Guild.Id);

        if (user == null)
        {
            user = new Quests
            {
                UserId = Context.User.Id,
                GuildId = Context.Guild.Id, 
                ten_daily = false,
                two_cases = false, 
                lvl_up_3 = false, 
                three_weekly = false, 
                lvl_up_7 = false,
                Forty_daily = false,
                twenty_hours_voice = false,
                eight_weeklu = false

            };
        }

        bool[] checkalluserquests = new bool[8] { user.ten_daily, user.two_cases, user.lvl_up_3, user.three_weekly, 
            user.lvl_up_7, user.Forty_daily, user.twenty_hours_voice, user.eight_weeklu };

    }
```

теперь я думаю, что нужно написать цикл где будет проверятся все столбы на значение true или false и там где false нужно чтобы они записывались в отдельные переменные

Comment: "я не понимаю как мне сделать проверку всей строки пользователя в бд на наличия true false" не совсем понятно о чем идет речь. Покажите пример этой строки

Comment: bool result1 = ds.All(x => x.) ну вот к примеру щас начал что-то писать как мне проверить все столбцы в одной строчке бд

Comment: Вам нужно проверить, что все колонки = true ?

Comment: @PavelPopov Да.

Comment: [Оно](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6087805/12888024)?

Comment: @aepot по коду видно, что оно но я ещё не тестил, я просто не понимаю как вы это находите?

Comment: @aepot но там вообще получение имен колонок(конечно если развить можно получить и значения), но через рефлексию, жесть) интересно а SQL-ем это можно как то проще сделать

Comment: Гугл находит `c# ef core get columns`. @PavelPopov ага, всё верно. А вообще, чтобы было подобное удобно и без костылей, надо правильно модель базы данных построить с учётом особенностeй SQL.

Comment: @aepot  нет это бред это видимо не то, щас отредактирую вопрос, чтобы понятнее было

Comment: отредактировал @aepot

Comment: Вы явно что-то не то делаете. Если вам нужно проверить все столбцы на true - сделайте вычисляемое поле в таблице, в котором и будет лежать нужный вам true/false. А вообще, странная какая-то таблица, слишком много в ней булевых столбцов.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko ну я только, что её создал поэтому нулей много

Comment: @whitetears не "нулевых столбцов", а **булевых** (bool) :) Вам бы хранить список уникальных квестов в отдельной таблице (`quests`), а факт прохождения конкретного квеста конкретным пользователем - в другой таблице (`user_quest_pass`), где будут поля: `Id`, `UserId`, `QuestId`, `IsPassed` . Тогда вам всего лишь нужно будет выбрать из таблицы `user_quest_pass` данные примерно так: `SELECT * FROM user_quest_pass WHERE UserId = @yourId AND IsPassed = '1'`. Либо, через EntityFramework `userQuestPass.Where(p => p.UserId == yourId && p.IsPassed)`

Comment: @AndreiKhotko отредактировал вопрос

Comment: Я бы вообще хранил в таблице число например int, как [битовые флаги](https://m.habr.com/ru/post/68322/), и использовал двоичную арифметику.

Comment: @whitetears если вы не планируете добавлять квесты, то ваш вариант подходит. Но если вы планируете в дальнейшем добавлять количество квестов, то рекомендую сделать так, как я описал в предыдущем комментарии